# Choosing an NLog target based on global log level

Tags: c#, wpf, logging, nlog

I'm trying to log to a file using NLog based on a globally-set log level.  I'm unsure if this is possible from everything I can dig up.

Essentially, I want to have a global setting in my `appconfig.json` that has the log level.  Default would be `Debug`, but `Trace` would be another option.  If I select `Debug`, I want to log everything from `Debug` up to `Fatal` in a file called `log-debug.txt`.  This seems pretty reasonable; it's the base tutorial case from what I can tell, and I've made that work.

Here's the other thing, though: if I set the global log level to `Trace`, I want *everything* from `Trace` on up to log to `log-trace.txt`.  My initial thought was to add a new config rule, so I added the second one in the `rules` collection, but from everything I've read that would end up with the debug messages in one file and the trace messages in another.

The purpose of this is extreme-case debugging (i.e., user doesn't have any idea how they got to that state, so flip the setting from "Debug" to "Trace", play with it again, and when you hit the bug send me the log-trace.txt), so splitting the debug and trace messages into different files would defeat the purpose.

How would I go about doing this?

This is a WPF app, so I'm setting the global level by using this in `app.xaml.cs`:

```csharp
serviceCollection.AddLogging(builder =>
{
    builder.ClearProviders();

    // Haven't written the code to pull it from the config file yet, but this is how
    // I would set it.
    builder.SetMinimumLevel(Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LogLevel.Trace);
    builder.AddNLog();
});
```

`appconfig.json`

```json
{
  "settings": {
    "logLevel": "Debug"
  },
  "NLog": {
    "internalLogLevel": "Info",
    "autoReload": true,
    "targets": {
      "logfile-debug": {
        "type": "File",
        "fileName": "log-debug.txt",
        "layout": "${longdate}|${level}|${message}|${exception:format=tostring}"
      },
      "logfile-trace": {
        "type": "File",
        "fileName": "log-trace.txt",
        "layout": "${longdate}|${level}|${message}|${exception:format=tostring}",
      },
      "logconsole": {
        "type": "Debugger",
        "layout": "${longdate}|${level}|${message}|${exception:format=tostring}"
      }
    },
    "rules": [
      {
        "logger": "*",
        "minLevel": "Debug",
        "writeTo": "logfile-debug,logconsole"
      },
      {
        "logger": "*",
        "minLevel": "Trace",
        "writeTo": "logfile-trace,logconsole"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
void EnableGlobalTrace(bool enable)
{
   NLog.GlobalDiagnosticsContext.Set("GlobalTraceLevel", enable ? "Trace" : "Off");
   NLog.LogManager.ReconfigureExistingLoggers();
}
```

And have the rules like this:

```json
    "rules": [
      {
        "logger": "*",
        "minLevel": "Debug",
        "writeTo": "logfile-debug,logconsole"
      },
      {
        "logger": "*",
        "minLevel": "${gdc:GlobalTraceLevel:whenEmpty=Off}",
        "writeTo": "logfile-trace"
      }
    ]
```

See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Filtering-log-messages#semi-dynamic-routing-rules

See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Environment-specific-NLog-Logging-Configuration

Comment: This worked perfectly.  The only downside was that the debug file was generated either way, but I solved that by applying the same thing you suggested with the trace rule to the debug rule.  Thank you!